# No italics in vim

Tags: neovim, filetype-markdown, plugin-vimwiki

I am using vimwiki on nvim 0.1.7 on Konsole 16.12.3 on Plasma 5.9.5 on Kubuntu 17.04.

Wiki text appears bold when it is between two stars. But when between two underscores, it does not appear in italic.

The same is the case even when I switch the format to markdown.

What is happening? How do I get to see the italic text?

Comment: Are italics enabled at all? Try to edit a simple html file like `:e test.html` and write `<em>italic</em>` into it. Does it appear in italic?

Comment: @apparat No. It does not. It just appears on a dark background.

Comment: Try to put this `let&t_ZH="\e[3m"` and `let &t_ZR="\e[23m"` in your vimrc and see if the html file works now.

Comment: @apparat No difference. It is just the same. BTW, I put a space between `let` and `&` in the first expression.

Answer (score 4):

It's possible your terminal doesn't support italics. Go through [this link](https://jsatk.us/vim-tmux-italics-and-insanity-9a96b69eeca6) (if you're interested in learning a little) to possibly fix your issue. Start at the paragraph with vimrc in it.

I'll provide a tl;dr transcription below

#### Transcription of above link.

1. type this into your shell: `echo -e "\e[3mfoo\e[23m"` if it shows up in italics, good we're halfway there already.
2. If it doesn't you might have to "patch" your shell to include italic support. I quote patch because if the terminal doesn't support it, then no matter what you patch in, it won't work. You'd have to try another terminal that does.

   2a. Enter this command: `infocmp -L $TERM > $TERM.terminfo`. It outputs all the details of your current `$TERM` in a nice format and puts them in a file that you can edit.

   2b. Using whatever tool you want, search for the `ritm` and `sitm`. Since we saw above that italics don't print to your terminal, they shouldn't exist.

   2c. Add the following to your $TERM.terminfo file `ritm=\E[23m` & `sitm=\E[3m`

   2d. Compile the new terminfo file by doing this: `tic -o ~/. $TERM.terminfo`

   2e. Kill and restart the tmux server, and you should now have italics capabilities.
3. Add the following to your `.vimrc` (Might not be necessary, you should test it on your system)

   - `set t_ZH=^[[3m` & `set t_ZR=^[[23m`

After all this, you should be good to go.